# Why does powershell say cl.exe is not recognized?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, cl

I have visual studio installed, and cl.exe runs perfectly fine after vcvarsall.bat has been run in cmd but in powershell it says it is not recognized.
cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\Ethos>vcvarsall.bat x64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.2.5
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\Users\Ethos>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.32.31332 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

The above works fine in cmd.

```
PS C:\Users\Ethos> vcvarsall.bat x64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.2.5
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
PS C:\Users\Ethos> cl
cl : The term 'cl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cl
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The above happens in power. Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- The following assumes that there isn't also a `vcvarsall.ps1` *PowerShell* script file, i.e. the PowerShell equivalent to the `vcvarsall.bat` *batch* file.
- If `vcvarsall.ps1` exists, simply call it instead (`.\vcvarsall.ps1` if located in the current dir, just `vcvarsall.bat` if located in one of the dirs. in `$env:PATH`)

  - If it doesn't exist, consider wrapping one of the solutions below in a PowerShell `function` that you can place in your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles); e.g.:

    ```bash
    function vcvarsall {
      cmd /c vcvarsall.bat @args '&&' (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path        
    }
    ```

---

From PowerShell, run the following (assuming that `vcvarsall.bat` is either in the current directory or in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`):

```bash
cmd /c vcvarsall.bat x64 '&&' (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
```

This **instructs `cmd.exe` to define the environment variables and then launches a *new* PowerShell session that *inherits* those environment variables**.

Note that the original PowerShell session will live on (as does `cmd.exe`, but it exits automatically when the nested PowerShell session ends), so when you `exit` the nested PowerShell session, you'll return to the original one.

---

Alternatively, if you prefer to start the new PowerShell session *in a new window*, call via `cmd.exe`'s `start` command:

```bash
cmd /c "vcvarsall.bat x64 && start `"$([Console]::Title)`" `"$((Get-Process -Id $PID).Path)`""
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

For batch file `vcvarsall.bat` to be effective, it must define environment variables for the *current process*.

This works from `cmd.exe`, because batch files execute *in-process* there.

By contrast, **PowerShell must run batch files in a `cmd.exe` *child* process**, as it cannot interpret batch files itself.
However, **environment variables defined in a *child* process are *not* seen by the calling process**.

Therefore, the above solutions launch an aux. `cmd.exe` process first, which defines the environment variables for itself, and then launches a new PowerShell session which *inherits* those environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old way of doing this.

Please install and start using `Windows Terminal` (WT) and `Powershell Core` (`pwsh.exe`), then WT will automatically setup the correct paths to the Dev version of the shell.

If not, you can modify your pwsh shortcut to:

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoExit -Command "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell f9d021a0 -SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdArguments """-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64"""}"
```

or run it manually (or add it to your powershell profile) with:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"

Enter-VsDevShell f9d021a0 -SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdArguments "-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64"
```

That should get you setup!